# Using Axios as an Alternative to request in nodejs

Tags: flutter, request, axios, authorization, hmacsha1

I am building a flutter application that requires oauth 1 authorization for one of the third party services I am using. Because flutter oauth 1 package is restricted I decided to use the oauth 1 package that npm provides. This is the code that is used to access the user generated access token from the site.

**I previously used request to make a call to the api endpoint first, to access the token and secondly to use the token recieved to make another call to a different resource endpoint**

How can I use **axios** to make the same request, emphasis on the fact that each request needs a hmac-sha1 signed signature in the header.

Thank you.

```
        consumer: {
            key: CONSUMER KEY,
            secret: CONSUMER SECRET,
        },
        signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
        hash_function(base_string, key) {
            return crypto
                .createHmac('sha1', key)
                .update(base_string)
                .digest('base64')
        },
    })

    const request_data = {
        url: 'https://www.instapaper.com/api/1/oauth/access_token/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { x_auth_username : USERNAME , x_auth_password : PASSWORD , x_auth_mode : 'client_auth' },
    } 

request(
        {
            url: request_data.url,
            form: request_data.data,
            method: request_data.method,
            headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data)),
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
            // Process your data here

            console.log(error);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(body);

        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer for this link to the issue created on github

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2771